# javascript function not triggered onchange if jquery autocomplete used

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

I have the following jquery autocomplete, which works fine.

Once the textbox changes, it runs the javascript function using `onchange="fieldchanged('1')`

The onchange runs fine if I manually type the text (don't select it from the autocomplete list).

But if I select any value from the autocomplete list, the `onchange="fieldchanged('1');"` is not triggered.

Any ideas what's wrong ?

**ASPX texbox:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtF10_D" runat="server" CssClass="desc"  onchange="fieldchanged('4');" ></asp:TextBox>
```

**AUTOCOMPLETE JQUERY:**

```
 var desc_options = ["Desc 1", "Desc 2", "Desc 3", "Desc 4", "Desc 5", "Desc 6", "Desc 7"];
 $('.desc').each(function () {
 var txt = $(this);
 txt.autocomplete({
 delay: 0,
 source: desc_options,                            
 });
});
```

JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION:

```
function fieldchanged(strCode) {                   
                    if (strCode == "1") {
                        var text = document.getElementById('txtOC7_1');
                        text.value = '0';
                    } else if (strCode == "2") {
                        var text = document.getElementById('txtOC8_1'); 
                        text.value = 'Y';
                    } else if (strCode == "3") {
                        var text = document.getElementById('txtOC9_1');
                        text.value = 'Y';
                    } else {

                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to listen change event for autocomplete.

```
$("#CompanyList").autocomplete({ 
      change: function() {
          $(this).trigger("change");
      }
   });
```

Comment: Ok, got it and it's working (the alert) but...how do I make the onchange js function trigger after the change ? Sorry but I am quite new at jquery...

Comment: that's perfect. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, here is http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ reference.

```
$( "#CompanyList" ).on( "autocompletechange", function( event, ui ) {
  alert('changed');
});
```